# how to set response status in asp.net web service method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Dear all how could im set response status in Asp.net Web service method ?

```
 <WebMethod()> _
<Script.Services.ScriptMethod(responseFormat:=Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function HelloWorld(ByVal name As String, ByVal userID As String, ByVal email As String, ByVal department As String, ByVal password1 As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Try
        Dim param(6) As SqlParameter
        param(0) = New SqlParameter("@RefId", 1)
        param(1) = New SqlParameter("@Name", name)
        param(2) = New SqlParameter("@UserName", userID)
        param(3) = New SqlParameter("@Email", email)
        param(4) = New SqlParameter("@Department", department)
        param(5) = New SqlParameter("@Password", password1)
        ' param(6) = New SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", "")

        result = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connStringShareMe, Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Users_Insert", param)

        Return "Done"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "500"    



        Return result
    End Try
End Function
```

i want to return 500 status code in response how can i do it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to access via the static HttpContext class:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500
```